# Facebook Wont' Scrape My Website

Tags: facebook, wordpress, share, meta-tags

http://losbanosdaily.com/?page_id=33

I'm working on this website here and facebook just won't scrape the page. I have meta tags in there and the facebook sdk. I checked my markup on w3 and it passed. I can't find anything wrong with it that would cause it not to want to scrape. Does anyone have any suggestions? I would really appreciate the help.

It is a wordpress website, but I can edit the source files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have warning form facebook when you look at their scraped data for your specific page

**Unable to download og:image:**    The image referenced by the url of og:image tag could not be downloaded.

**og:image should be larger:**  Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://losbanosdaily.com/wp-content/themes/NewsPulse/images/blackcow.png%20Scheme' will be used instead.

**Parser Mismatched Metadata:** The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'article:tag'

this is in the `og:Image` tag that Facebook is reading

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://losbanosdaily.com/wp-content/themes/NewsPulse/images/blackcow.png Scheme  " />
```

To get the scrapped details of your site - along with any warnings or errors use the [FaceBook Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: Okay, I fixed the meta content attribute value. The thumbnail I'll have to dig in there and have it scale the thumbnails to 200x200, odd though, some posts did show up with those images. You can see some posts here https://www.facebook.com/Losbanosdaily (though I've change the URL since so they may be broken)

Comment: How did you scrape? I can't even get it to scrape on my browser?

Comment: Thanks Scott, a little bit after those edits it started working again. Thank you very much! You're a lifesaver.

Comment: Oh man, this is really frustrating. The scraper doesn't work again and now it's doing the same thing. http://losbanosdaily.com/man-breaks-down-at-country-waffles-after-waitress-asks-how-many/

Comment: @FelipeTadeo - now that you have the debugger tool , you should be able to play around with it to get it to work